# How to hide the page on load indicating in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am using ASP.NET 2.0 and AJAX extension tool.

I already created loading indicator on button submit.  When I will click the button, the loading indicator will show after redirecting to the next page.  But, I want to hide the page until processing has completed (after that redirect to next page).

I am using the following code:

```
 <td style="width: 100px; height: 26px;">
                  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                </asp:ScriptManager> 
                <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" DynamicLayout="false" runat="server">
    <ProgressTemplate>
    <img src="Images/loading.gif" alt="Images/loading.gif" style="z-index: 100; left: 21px; position: absolute; top: 64px" />

    </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
                 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                    <dx:ASPxButton ID="btnOk" ClientInstanceName="btnok" runat="server" Style="z-index: 100; left: 90px; position: absolute;
                    top: 108px" Text="OK" Width="61px" BackColor="Gainsboro" OnClick="btnOk_Click" AutoPostBack="False" >
                    <DisabledStyle>
                        <Border BorderColor="Teal" />
                    </DisabledStyle>
                        <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) {
                    ShowloadingImage();
                        }" />


                </dx:ASPxButton>
               </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: So you want a 'loading' image to redirect from the current page?  Or are you performing some complex interaction server-side that should redirect once it has processed?

Answer (score 1):

To "hide" your page you can make an overlay div over all, using this css

```
.OverAll
{
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
   position:fixed;
   left:0;
   top:0;
   z-index:2 !important;
   background-color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using jquery we can hide the page on page loading...I am using following code

```
       $(function() { 
    ($.unblockUI);   
    $('#pnlLogin_btnOk').click(function() {
        $.blockUI({ message: '<img src="Images/loading.gif" />' });
    });
});
```